# "SQL command not properly ended" when using subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, subquery

I have the following query working:

```
select 
    a.column_value as artigo 
from 
    encomenda e, table(e.artigos) a 
where 
    e.id = 2;
```

This query returns the following output (one row of type `menu_t` and another of type `bebida_menu_t`). Note that this isn't simple text, but an object of a type defined by myself, since this is an object-relational database.

[image: Output of working query]

From that result, I want to extract only the `menu_t` rows. So, I've tried the following query:

```
select * 
from (select 
          a.column_value as artigo 
      from 
          encomenda e, table(e.artigos) a 
      where e.id = 2) as subquery 
where 
    subquery.artigo is of (menu_t);
```

Which gives me the error

> 933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

and I can't understand why.

**UPDATE:**

Seems the problem is the `as` keyword. So, it should be:

```
select * 
from (select 
          a.column_value as artigo 
      from 
          encomenda e, table(e.artigos) a 
      where e.id = 2) subquery --removed the 'as' here
where 
    value(subquery.artigo) is of (menu_t); --added value() because they were inconsistent types
```

However, now I am getting the error saying that `subquery.artigo` is an invalid identifier.

> 904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: In fact `AS` is used in MySQL but not in ORACLE; remove it for the column name `artigo` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to fix the first problem, as I said in the update, in Oracle we shouldn't use the `as` keyword on aliases. So, the query becomes:

```
select * 
from (select 
          a.column_value artigo 
      from 
          encomenda e, table(e.artigos) a 
      where e.id = 2) subquery 
where 
    subquery.artigo is of (menu_t);
```

But after this, I came up with another error, as described in the update. What was happening was that I was trying use `is of` in a `REF`, and it was warning me that it was an invalid identifier, but took me some time and many tries to realize the correct query. So, I needed to use `deref()` on the `art.column_value` column.

Afterall, I don't even need a nested subquery. The final query is:

```
select value(e).id id, art.column_value artigo 
from encomenda e, table(e.artigos) art 
where e.id = 2 and 
deref(art.column_value) is of (menu_t);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
where subquery.artigo is of (menu_t);
```

To

```
where subquery.artigo LIKE '%MENU_T';
```

Comment: I still get the same error. Why shouldn't `is of` be valid anyway?

Comment: What do you think `is of` does and what do you know about it?

Comment: This is an object-relational database and `menu_t` and `bebida_menu_t` are types defined by myself. I guess `is of` checks if they are of that type, similar to `instanceof` of Java, for example.

Comment: The problem was the `as` keyword on the subquery alias. But I still got an error. Please, check my original post.